# How to Remove the blog name from a post,page,or archive title in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

**How can the blog name be removed from the title of a post,page,or archive without using S.E.O plugins?**

The blog name is being appended to the title of a post,page,and archive using the following code from header.php :

`<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Which creates the title:

> Name of Post/Page/Archive/... | Blog name

**However, I only want it to display the title like this:**

> Name of Post/Page/Archive/...

Comment: Look into _header.php_ and see if there is `bloginfo('blogname')` in the title tag. If so, remove it.

Comment: @vard it was in old version of wp, there is only `<?php wp_head(); ?>` header.php doesn't have title tag (function wp_head adds it)

Comment: Check on [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95152/62744) it might help

Comment: @vard yeah.. it helped, I have to add only the second code

Comment: Clarified what the OP wants his answer to do or look like.